# Is it permissible to use cash-back credit cards and accounts?

Tags: halal-haram, riba

My concern and question is, nowadays in the USA many credit cards companies are giving cash-back rewards.  Some checking accounts (e.g. Discover) also give cash-back points and rewards bonuses for people who open accounts with them.

My question is, are these cash-back points, reward bonuses and the like which you get from a credit card company or checking account bank permissible from an Islamic perspective?

Comment: I really smiled when I read this question. You are asking for the ruling on cash back rewards on a credit card (which intrinsically carries Riba rules on it).

Comment: Yes, @AmericanMuslim is correct. By it's nature, the credit card system can never be separated from Riba. Some scholars permit this due to the situation, because as long as you always pay it on time you can avoid the Riba.

Comment: Cash-back bonuses are simply a marketing trick to make people buy more using their credit cards. But I think you can treat it as a discount or prize.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should notice that working or getting every money which is related to Rabawi transaction is considered as a haram practice. But in other cases which is not related to Rabawi transaction, it seems not to be haram if the mentioned bank is giving it to you as an incentive. (As far as I know).

**Reference:**

- [portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir/node/7353/?ref=sbttl#gsc.tab=0)